# How to aknowledge paternity of a 24 years old in South Africa and let her benefit from her EU citizenship

Tags: citizenship, italy, south-african-citizens, italy-aire

My brother is an Italian citizen and fathered a child during a holiday in South Africa in 1997, he aknowledged the daughter as his but not on her birth certificate where in fact her mother named another man as her father.

Although he has never met her, my brother knows she is his child and would like to aknowledge it officially.

She is a South African citizen and would like to aquire his surname and citizenship in due course.

What are the first steps to take in order to do this? Taking into account that my brother currently lives in the UK and the daughter in South Africa

Comment: Citizenship is a matter for each individual state in the EU (and all other countries as well). No answer is possible without knowing the country of your brother's citizenship, and probably the country of his daughter's birth...which might be South Africa, but isn't explicitly stated.

Comment: Does "acknowledged the daughter" mean his name is on her birth certificate?

Comment: I have edited some info so as to make it clearer, thanks

Comment: Countries normally have a process to amend the father’s name on a birth certificate, subject to proof that the man named on the certificate is not the natural father of the child. Examples of proof could include: a DNA test record from an approved tester, a court order, evidence that confirms the name of the true biological father, other evidence that confirms the recorded father could not have been the child’s natural father of paternity eg DNA

Comment: Legal basis: [Italian Citizenship](https://www.esteri.it/mae/en/servizi/stranieri/cittadinanza_0.html) *A minor who is recognized by an Italian citizen to be of Italian parentage or is declared to be of Italian parentage through a judiciary ruling on paternity / maternity (Article 2, paragraph 1, of Law No. 91/92).* And: *If the recognition or judicial ruling regards **persons of legal age**, they acquire Italian citizenship only if, within a year since the recognition or the judicial ruling, they express their will to this end, through a declaration "of election of citizenship"...*

Comment: The father (as a resident of Italy) must go through the process of getting the child registered into the Italian Civil Registry (A.P.R., Anagrafe Popolazione Residente). Afterwhich the (non-minor) child applies for recognition of citizenship at the responsible consulate within 1 year.

Comment: @TomasBy Sorry, overlooked that. Then the father will have to register the child through the [Registry of Italians Resident Abroad (A.I.R.E.)](https://www.esteri.it/mae/en/servizi/italiani-all-estero/aire_0.html) system, which will eventually land in the A.P.R. The father should enquire from the consulate what exactly is needed ('judiciary ruling on paternity' etc.) for the registration.

Comment: @MarkJohnson it seems as though all of this information would be better presented in an answer.

Comment: @phoog Most of this information can be found in other answers. Searching with the **italy-aire** tag should list those questions. The problem here is that the exact process for 'judiciary ruling on paternity' cannot be answered by me.